# PHP: like/dislike counter

Tags: php, mysql

I have a comics website where I'd like to allow users to vote **once** per comic and once per piece of artwork.

There seems to be two problems with my code:

1) I only want one user voting once per image... so I want to capture their information and store it in a database. I have a ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but it gives me the following syntax error even though I haven't found ANYTHING wrong with it:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table = VALUES(table), imgid = VALUES(imgid)' at line 7
```

An example of it allowing multiple entries into the database for the same IP:

[image]

2) It's still allowing one user to vote multiple times.

```
    $sql = "SELECT ip FROM votes WHERE ip = \"".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\" AND table_name = $table AND imgid = $imgid";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
var_dump($result);
```

**Full code:**

```
<?php 
include 'dbconnect.php';
$site = $_GET['_site'];
$imgid = intval($_GET['_id']);
$input = $_GET['_choice'];


if ($site == "artwork") {
   $table = "artwork";
}
else {
   $table = "comics";
}

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT like_count, dislike_count FROM $table WHERE id = $imgid");

list($likes, $dislikes) = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

$sql = "INSERT INTO 
            votes (ip, table_name, imgid) 
        VALUES 
            (\"".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\", \"$table\", $imgid)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            ip = VALUES(ip),
            table = VALUES(table),
            imgid = VALUES(imgid)";

$mysqli->query($sql);
echo $mysqli->error;
echo "<br/>";

$sql = "SELECT ip FROM votes WHERE ip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' AND table_name = '$table' AND imgid = $imgid";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
echo $mysqli->error;

if ($result->num_rows == 0) { 
    if ($input == "like") {
        $sql = "UPDATE $table SET like_count = like_count + 1 WHERE id = $imgid";
        $mysqli->query($sql);           
        $likes++;
    }
    else if ($input == "dislike") {
        $sql = "UPDATE $table SET dislike_count = dislike_count + 1 WHERE id = $imgid";
        $mysqli->query($sql);
        $dislikes++;        
    }
echo "Likes: " . $likes . ", Dislikes: " . $dislikes;
}
else {
    echo "You have already voted";
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

Echoing out sql:

```
echo "sql: ". $sql;
```

Produces:

```
sql: INSERT INTO votes (ip, table_name, imgid) VALUES ("127.0.0.1", "comics", 34) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ip = VALUES(ip), table = VALUES(table), imgid = VALUES(imgid)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You know that IPs are not unique by user, right?

Comment: @markus-tharkun I couldn't think of another way to ensure that only a user could only vote once per comic.

Comment: Users need to have an account for it to really work! Just use some openID and a simple sign on.

Comment: @markus-tharkun It's supposed to be an open-browsing comics website. The last thing I wanted to do is make users log in. Is getting their IPs not enough of a catch?

Comment: @markus-tharkun hey markus, any other thoughts why those two errors may be happening?

Comment: For some reason you're not using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) with `mysqli` could be creating all kinds of [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Using string interpolation to construct SQL queries is not a very safe technique. Placeholders will always properly handle string values so you don't end up stuck on silly problems like this.

Comment: @tadman Thanks Tadman. I am looking to go live with this website tomorrow though... I was going to rework everything into prepared statements after. Do you have any advice about this specific problem? It's my final issue before I launch my comics site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is `table` is one of the [MySQL reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) but you're trying to use it as a column name. Your column is actually called `table_name` based on your question, though.

A query with placeholders looks like:

```
INSERT INTO votes (ip, table_name, imgid) 
  VALUES (?, ?, ?)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    ip=VALUES(ip),
    table_name= VALUES(table_name),
    imgid=VALUES(imgid)
```

Remember with `mysqli` you can execute this query by doing this:

```
$sth = $mysqli->prepare("...");
$sth->bind_param("sss", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $table, $imgid);
$sth->execute();
```

The documentation describes this process in more detail, but the `"sss"` thing refers to three strings, and the three values are passed in as parameters.

You should probably be using [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) as it's a lot less fussy to use than `mysqli`. Even better would be to use a database framework like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) to do a lot of the SQL dirty work for you. Even better still would be to use a framework like [CodeIgnighter](http://codeignighter.com/), [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) or [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com/) to give you a foundation to build on. Constructing applications by hand from the ground up is extremely time-consuming and significantly more error prone.

Another thing to note is you should try and use consistent naming in your code. You refer to `$table` as a value for `table_name`, so it should presumably be `$table_name` to start with.

Comment: Thank you for advice on other frameworks! I've promised my fans i'll release the site soon, so I'll change to cake php after I release it. Also, I'm never using "table", I'm always using it as a variable "$table", which should be okay, right? My column for "votes" table is indeed called "table_name", but I first need to get the like/dislike count from the "comics" or "artwork" tables.

Comment: If a variable correlates with the `table_name` column, I'm saying it should probably be called `$table_name` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You query fails but you do not check that and try to use $result but it is not an object bug `false`. And it fails, because you should be like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT ip FROM votes WHERE ip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' AND table_name = $table AND imgid = $imgid";
```

(string values are quoted with single quote `'`)

Comment: I tried that before. This doesn't seem to be working, and produces the same error :/

Comment: sure. `echo $mysqli->error;` after your failing query. or `echo $sql;` and manual attempt in console or phpmyadmin

Comment: Error: Unknown column 'comics' in 'where clause'. But I don't see what the issue is..

Comment: ain't message clear enough? ;) 
 check how is your column named **in db** - maybe you got typo, maybe you got trailing space? if none dump table struct and add to question

Comment: Lol. K I found it... needed tick marks around '$table' because it's looking for a string. Also, Do you happen to know why ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is allowing multiple entries of the same ip? The code is above

Comment: Have you set the IP and table_name as primary key?

Comment: @take IP is a Primary Key, yes.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com I've updated my question. I am trying to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (following this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450682/insert-into-on-duplicate-key-update-for-multiple-items/450695#450695) but have had NO luck :(

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com any other ideas?

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com I'm not sure what you mean by "example query". The code above is up to date, along with the errors I am getting.

Comment: there's no schema. "example query" is the query you try to execute. just `echo $sql;` and paste the output.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com (ALSO ADDED ABOVE)  sql: INSERT INTO votes (ip, table_name, imgid) VALUES ("127.0.0.1", "comics", 34) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ip = VALUES(ip), table = VALUES(table), imgid = VALUES(imgid)

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com Any ideas on my response?